# How to solve this problem in php and html?

Tags: php, html, arrays

I would like to print 1000 numbers with the HTML tag below numbers and compare with a vector of objects.

```
<?php
for ($i = 1; $i <= 1000; $i++) {
    foreach ($resposta as $row) {
?>
        <?php if ($row['estado_idestado'] == 5 && $row['numero_ecolhido'] == $i) { ?>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="number_2" class="rifa_number item_pago" data-id="179930" data-rifa-number="2" data-name="">
                <?php echo $i; ?>
            </a>
        <?php } elseif ($row['estado_idestado'] == 4 && $row['numero_ecolhido'] == $i) { ?>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="number_10" class="rifa_number item_reservado" data-id="279676" data-rifa-number="10" data-name="">
            <?php
                echo $i;
            ?>
            </a>
        <?php
            } else {
        ?>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="number_3" class="rifa_number item_disponivel" data-id="" data-rifa-number="3" data-name="">
            <?php
                echo $i;
            ?>
            </a>
        <?php
            }
        ?>
    <?php
    }
}
?>
```

Note that the query in the vector is to define the class of `<a> </a>`, and I would like it to print 1000 number .... the code should look like the image below, but I can not find a logic that solves this problem.

[image]

Comment: I forgot to close the class over there.

Comment: If you need to make changes to your question - just use [Edit]

Comment: What exactly do you mean with: "1000 numbers with the html tag below numbers"? Can you give an example of the html code which you wanna generate just for a few numbers? In which cases which classes should be set or are class1, class2, class3 the correct names? The echo $i looks suspicious.

Comment: I created before one of 1000 interactions in php

Answer (score 0):

the question is not clear and there is couple of obvious problems up there:
- the hard coded id attribute , that will make a repetitive id , which will make your javascript act funny.
- the `foreach` is not necessary at all and you will have a  repetitive action that you do not want.
- the one thing is not clear if the array `$resposta` has less than 1000 item or more than 1000 item.

if the array `$resposta` has less than 1000 item you should build an empty array of 1000 item and merge the 2 arrays, this way you will have `$resposta` has 1000 item

in my code i assume that `$resposta` has a 1000 item whether you fill it yourself or you get it from database with 1000 item.

```
<?php
    for($i = 0; $i<=1000; $i++) {
      if( $resposta[$i]['estado_idestado']==5 && $resposta[$i]['numero_ecolhido']==$i ){ 
?>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="number_2" class="rifa_number item_pago" data-id="179930" data-rifa-number="2" data-name=""> <?php echo $i;  ?> </a>

<?php
     }elseif( $resposta[$i]['estado_idestado']==4 && $resposta[$i]['numero_ecolhido']==$i ){  
?>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="number_10" class="rifa_number item_reservado" data-id="279676" data-rifa-number="10" data-name=""><?php  echo $i;  ?></a>

<?php 
    }else{ 
?>

 <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="number_3" class="rifa_number item_disponivel" data-id="" data-rifa-number="3" data-name=""><?php   echo $i; ?></a>

    <?php
  next($resposta)
                }
        }
    ?>
```

i did not change the hard coded id attributes , you should do it your self as your logic needs.

if the $resposta has not enough items (the 1000 items) it will produce a Notice, you can suppress the Notice by addig @ to the line that produce  the error or use the `error_reporting()` function

---

**Edit : how to make the array of desired length**

simply you can use `array_pad() function` for example:

```
$arr = [
    ['id'=>0,'name'=>'mark'],
    ['id'=>1,'name'=>'micheal'],    
    ['id'=>2,'name'=>'ahmed'],
    ['id'=>3,'name'=>'grin'],
    ['id'=>4,'name'=>'Torvi'],
    ['id'=>5,'name'=>'mohamed'],
    ['id'=>6,'name'=>'kayla'],  
];

$new = array_pad($arr, 20,0);
```

this will produce array of 20 elements, and from index 7 it will fill with zeros.
[function docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-pad.php)

so in our case here

```
$newresposta = array_pad( $resposta,1000,0);
```

and then you can continue with the code in the original answer after adding previous line above.

Comment: The id will be changed later, but the array could not have a dimension from 0 to 1000, the code did not work!

Comment: you can do further step prior to the code above , i have mentioned this point above also, use range() function to make an empty array then merge it, i will update the answer below the original answer

Comment: i figure out there is another more neat way then range i will add it in the edited answer